# Why is my YN-568EX not switching to M, Multi mode from ETTL?

Tags: flash, troubleshooting, yongnuo

Suddenly my flash is acting weird. It's not switching to modes from ETTL even when it's no camera. But if I long press the mode button it changes to slave and wireless mode and again if I try to change it to M/Multi it didn't work. Can anyone please advise how to resolve this issue? I have check in this forum others are also having the issue and they have answered it yet. Please share if anyone able to resolve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Yongnuo 568EX speedlight not switching to manual mode?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/40303/how-to-fix-yongnuo-568ex-speedlight-not-switching-to-manual-mode)

Comment: How are you using the flash? Attached to the hot shoe? Via wireless radio triggers? Using Canon's *optical* wireless system with a built in flash on a compatible camera? What camera model are you using with the flash?