# Why won't my off-camera YN568EX II stay in manual mode?

Tags: off-camera-flash, yongnuo

I am using my Yongnuo YN568EX II on a YN622C wireless trigger. When I put it in manual mode it will only stay in that mode for a few seconds and reverts back to E-TTL. How can I get it to stay in manual mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Yongnuo 568EX speedlight not switching to manual mode?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/40303/how-to-fix-yongnuo-568ex-speedlight-not-switching-to-manual-mode)

Comment: How are you trying to put the flash in manual mode? Via the flash's control panel, the trigger's controls, or the camera's flash settings?